# SAGA and local transactions with Kafka and Postgres in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-data-jpa, microservices, rdbms, spring-kafka, saga

Haven't worked with SAGAs and `spring-kafka` (and `spring-cloud-stream-kafka-binder`) for a while.

Context: there are several (3+) `Spring-boot` microservices that have to span business transaction in order to keep data in eventually consistent state. They use **Database-per-Service** approach (each service stores data in **Postgres**) and collaborate via **Kafka** as an **Event-Store**.

I'm going to apply **SAGA** (either choreography or orchestration approach, let's stick to the first one) to manage transaction over multiple services.

The question is: how to support local transactions when using **RDBMS (Postgres)** as a data store along with **Kafka** as an **Event-Store/messaging middleware**?

In nowadays, does actually spring-kafka support JTA transactions and would it be enough to wrap RDBMS and Kafka Producer into `@Transactional` methods? Or do we still have to apply some of Transactional microservices patterns (like **Transactional Outbox**, **Transaction Log Tailing** or **Polling Publisher**)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Kafka does not support JTA/XA. The best you can do is "Best Effort 1PC" - see [Dave Syer's Javaworld article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html); you have to handle possible duplicates.

Spring for Apache Kafka provides the `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager`; for consumer-initiated transactions, the CKTM should be injected into the listener container.

The CKTM should have the KTM first, followed by the RDBMS, so the RDBMS transaction will be committed first; if it fails, the Kafka tx will roll back and the record redelivered. If the DB succeeds but Kafka fails, the record will be redelivered (with default configuration).

For producer-only transactions, you can use `@Transactional`. In that case, the TM can just be the RDBMS TM and Spring-Kafka will synchronize a local Kafka transaction, committing last.

[See here for more information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions).